# What's wrong with HTTPS?

Tags: bug, ssl, meta

[image: What's wrong with certificate?]

What's wrong with security certificate for this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name in the certificate does not match the host name to use. The certificate is valid for lots of different names and includes wildcards such as `*.meta.stackexchange.com` (which would match against `unix.meta.stackexchange.com`) but no name which matches against `meta.unix.stackexchange.com`. Note that the included `*.stackexchange.com` will not match because a wildcard matches only a single label, i.e. `meta` or `unix` but not `meta.unix`.

Comment: Any ideas if that can be fixed?

Comment: Make the certificate match the hostname, that is either change the certificate or the name used to access the site.

Comment: So that doubles the cost of certificates for all SO meta sites, so the solution is to go for cheaper SSL provider. Or is is possible to have a certificate that allows to match `*.*.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Multiple wildcards within a single entry are not possible, but you can have multiple entries in the subject alternative section within the same certificate and each of these can use wildcards.

Comment: Some Background: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: @techtonik - it isn't just cost. It is also about management. Most SE sites fall under a single `*.stackexchange.com` cert. with `meta.*.stackexchange.com` would be well over 100 certificates. That's a significant cost in managing them. Multiple wildcards are _technically_ possible (but due to past abuse, no provider will do them).

Comment: @Oded:   Multiple wildcards in a single name are not supported by current browsers. And [RFC6125](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#page-27) explicitly restricts wildcards to the leftmost label and thus effectively prohibits multiple wildcard inside a single entry too (there is only a single leftmost label).

Comment: @Oded, so the problem is on the side of certificate agency that doesn't provide API to issue certificates automatically? I don't believe that SO doesn't use some tools like Ansible to automate certificate management on their side.